# Why MySQL COUNT(*) query return empty set?

Tags: mysql, count

I have 3 tables:

- `user` (a table of users)
- `post` (a table of posts with a field author which is a `FOREIGN KEY` to user id)
- `friend` (a table which represents a relation user-to-user with `FOREIGN KEY` fields: `user_id` and `friend`

I have a query where I can set values for filter the results like this (from Java PreparedStatement):

```
SELECT post.* FROM post, friend WHERE friend.user_id = ? AND post.author = friend.friend AND post.body LIKE ? AND post.date BETWEEN ? AND ? LIMIT ?,?
```

Inserting values in the query like this:

```
SELECT post.* FROM post, friend WHERE friend.user_id = 2 AND post.author = friend.friend AND post.body LIKE '%word%' AND post.date BETWEEN '2016-02-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-01 00:00:00' LIMIT 1,5;
```

I get a list of 5 posts. But now, I want to get the number of results. I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post, friend WHERE friend.user_id = 2 AND post.author = friend.friend AND post.body LIKE '%word%' AND post.date BETWEEN '2016-02-10 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-01 00:00:00' LIMIT 1,5;
```

But I get `Empty set`. Why do I get this instead 5?

**EDIT:**

If it helps, I post the db code and some inserts of data.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname;
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
USE dbname;

CREATE TABLE user (
    id          INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL    UNIQUE,
    name        VARCHAR(70)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE post (
    id         INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date       DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    title      VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    body       VARCHAR(1000)   NOT NULL,
    author     INT             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE friend (
    user_id     INT             NOT NULL,
    friend      INT             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, friend)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE post
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_autor_post(author) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE friend
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_user_id(user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE friend
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_friend_id(friend) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;


INSERT INTO user VALUES(null, "uname1", "User 1");
INSERT INTO user VALUES(null, "uname2", "User 2");
INSERT INTO user VALUES(null, "uname3", "User 3");
INSERT INTO user VALUES(null, "uname4", "User 4");
INSERT INTO user VALUES(null, "uname5", "User 5");

INSERT INTO friend VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(1,3);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(1,4);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(1,5);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(2,1);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(2,5);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(2,4);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(2,3);

INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-01 10:00:00', "Title post 1", "Body 1", 1);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-01 10:00:00', "Title post 2", "Body 2", 1);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-01 10:20:40', "Title post 3", "Body 3", 1);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-01 10:20:00', "Title post 4", "Body 4", 4);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-02-05 10:00:00', "Title post 5", "Body 5", 5);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-05 10:00:00', "Title post 6", "Body 6", 2);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-02-01 22:00:00', "Title post 7", "Body 7", 2);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-02-01 10:00:00', "Title post 8", "Body 8", 3);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-02 10:00:00', "Title post 9", "Body 9", 5);
INSERT INTO post values (null, '2016-01-01 10:40:00', "Title post 10", "Body 10", 1);
```

Query:

```
SELECT post.* FROM post, friend WHERE friend.user_id = 2 AND post.author = friend.friend AND post.body LIKE '%%' AND post.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-01 00:00:00' LIMIT 1,5;
```

Return:

```
+----+---------------------+--------------+--------+--------+
| id | date                | title        | body   | author |
+----+---------------------+--------------+--------+--------+
|  2 | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | Title post 2 | Body 2 |      1 |
|  3 | 2016-01-01 10:20:40 | Title post 3 | Body 3 |      1 |
|  4 | 2016-01-01 10:20:00 | Title post 4 | Body 4 |      4 |
|  5 | 2016-02-05 10:00:00 | Title post 5 | Body 5 |      5 |
|  8 | 2016-02-01 10:00:00 | Title post 8 | Body 8 |      3 |
+----+---------------------+--------------+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post, friend WHERE friend.user_id = 2 AND post.author = friend.friend AND post.body LIKE '%%' AND post.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-01 00:00:00' LIMIT 1,5;
```

Return:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The same using `COUNT(post.id)`, `COUNT(post.body)`, `SUM(1)`, `SUM(post.id)`.
Error using `COUNT(post.*)`:

Comment: Try `COUNT(post.*)` - does it work?

Comment: you should get 5 back, how are you grabbing the value, maybe try `COUNT(*) as mycount` so that you can refer to the column name `mycount`

Comment: `COUNT(post.*)` throw me a syntax error.

Comment: Using an alias for the column I get the same `Empty set`

Comment: that is odd, try `SUM(1) as mycount` and see if you get what you want

Comment: or `COUNT(post.body)` or any other field in `post`.

Comment: The same in both cases.

Comment: Would you please post the Java query and reporting code?  Maybe it's something in the setup of the query or the reporting of the results.

Comment: I have added the sql code and the queries and results.
I am not using java yet. First I test the queries and then I implement it on Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCount FROM (SELECT 
  post.* 
FROM
  post,
  friend 
WHERE friend.user_id = 2 
  AND post.author = friend.friend 
  AND post.body LIKE '%%' 
  AND post.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND '2016-12-01 00:00:00' 
LIMIT 1, 5) AS a ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a similar query on my own database and got the same result as you.  I changed the limit from 1,5 to 0,5 and got the desired result.  I don't know if that's an option for you or not.

Comment: Good.
That's not an option for me because I need `LIMIT` to filter the result, and then `COUNT` it. But that helps me to understand what's happening.
Thanks.
I suposse that `LIMIT` is applying at the end, `LIMIT`ing the `COUNT` rows (only 1).

Comment: Then just wrap the thing in a select statement. Ex: 
SELECT 
  count(*) 
  FROM 
  (<your query here>) as ct;

Comment: I think I understand what's happening.  The way limit is applied is it's the last thing to run in this particular instance.  So the query runs, gets a count, which is your single result that would be returned.  The limit is then applied, which since the offset is 1, you are skipping the first (and only) result  and therefor getting no results at all.